# Special meaning of "$a$" in grep command

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to learn shell scripting, and I am trying different things. While I was practicing I came across `grep "$a$" file1` and couldn't understand the output.

I know the difference that single quotes takes the literal meaning and the double quoting tries to find the special meaning like the `$a` is supposed to be variable `$`.

I have `file1` with content

```
#!/bin/sh
a=1
b=1
echo $a
echo $b
for I in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
do
    c=a
    b=$a
    b=$(($a+$c))
    echo $b
done
```

`grep "$a$" file1` gives me the whole `file1` as output where
`grep '$a$' file1` gives me output as it is supposed to give, like the line which ends in `$a`.

Please explain why it gives the whole file content as output when `grep "$a$"` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with `^` and `$` in a grep pattern symbolizes beginning and end respectively.

In

```
grep "$a$" file1
```

`$a` undergoes expansion because it is inside double quotes. In your case `$a` should be undefined. So the The result of `"$a$"` is `$` which matches the end of every line, so you will get  the entire file as output. To verify this assign some test value to `a` and then run grep.

```
a="TestValue" # Before running grep
grep "$a$" file1
```

I bet you'll get nothing as output.

Now if you want to have a literal '$' inside the double quote. then you need to do

```
grep "\$a$" file1 # See the first $ is escaped
```

Above command will give you all the lines that end with `$a`

```
echo $a
b=$a
```

Now if you're tired of escaping you may very well use single quotes as below

```
grep '$a$' file1
# The first $ is literal $, and the last one symbolizes end of file.
# More over variable-expansion doesn't take place inside single quotes.
```

<sup>**Note :** The `a=1` inside the `file1` has no influence on the grep result as the `file1` is just an input to `grep`.</sup>

Comment: The OP has `a=1` defined -- or did they edit that in since your answer was written?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special meaning.

I don't see any `grep` in your code. I assume your are grepping from the command line and that the variable `a` is undefined. Consequently, `grep "$a$"` expands to `grep "$"` (`$a` expands to nothing) and `grep $` matches every line since `$` matches the end of line.

[update] By 'expand', I mean shell variable expansion. Because `$a` is between double quotes, the shell is replacing `$a` with the value of variable `a` (which is undefined). Your `grep '$a$'` yields the expected result because any string between single quotes is always left untouched by the shell. Try `echo "$a$"` vs  `echo '$a$'`.

Answer (score 0):

## `"$a$"`

The string `"$a$"` is expanded to the value of `$a` shell variable followed by literal `$` (why? see below). If the `$a` variable is unset, its value is interpreted as an empty string, and the result of expansion is `"$"` (only the dollar sign).

### Why the last dollar sign is not expanded?**

The basic form of [parameter expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) is `"${PARAMETER}"`. The braces are not required, if `PARAMETER` is not a positional parameter with more than one digit (`10`, `11`, etc.), and if `PARAMETER` is not followed by a character that is not to be interpreted as part of its name. Since `$` begins next parameter expansion, command substitution, or arithmetic expansion, it is not interpreted as a part of the `a` parameter name in our case.

Since nothing is followed by the last `$`, it doesn't conform to any kind of expansion, and left intact.

### How Grep interprets the pattern

Since the [match-end-of-line operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Match_002dend_002dof_002dline-Operator.html#Match_002dend_002dof_002dline-Operator) (`$`) matches the empty string either at the end of the string or before a newline character in the string, the pattern `$` matches *any line*.

Therefore, `grep "$a$" file` will match and print all lines in `file`, if `$a` is empty.

## `'$a$'`

Single quotes protect the string from any expansion (interpretation of special characters). That is, the string is passed to the command as is.

In the case of `grep '$a$' file` invocation, the pattern matches `"$a"` string *at the end of the line*. The following describes why.

The last `$` means the end of the line, as we know. The rest of dollar signs are interpreted depending on the pattern. It can be interpreted either as literal dollar sign, or the end of the line.

In the following cases, `$` represents the end-of-line operator. Otherwise, `$` is ordinary.

- If the `$` is last in the pattern, as in `foo$`.
- The [syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Predefined-Syntaxes.html#Predefined-Syntaxes) bit `RE_CONTEXT_INDEP_ANCHORS` is set, and is outside a bracket expression.
- It ends an open-group or alternation operator expression, e.g. `'\(b$\)'`, or `'\(b$\)\|a'`.

Since

- the first `$` in our pattern is obviously not last,
- you are using the basic `RE_SYNTAX_GREP` [syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Predefined-Syntaxes.html#Predefined-Syntaxes), i.e. BRE,
- and the open-group/alternation is not used,

the first dollar sign is *ordinary* in `$a$`.

### When the first `$` is not *ordinary*?

It is not ordinary, for example, in the case of extended regular expressions. That is, with the `-E` or `-P` options, or with `egrep` or `pgrep` commands, for instance (where the `RE_CONTEXT_INDEP_ANCHORS` syntax bit is set).

## Escaping the dollar sign

Consider escaping the dollar sign even though it is interpreted as literal `$` in the basic regular expressions. It will develop a good habit.

To escape the dollar sign within single quotes use a backslash: `'\$a$'`.

Within double quotes the backslash has special meaning, so you need to escape the backslash itself: `"\\\$a\$"`.